# Entity Framework Core/.NET Core does not consistently return results

Tags: mysql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a very basic method in a class called UserRepository. It's supposed to return a User object with a given userId.

```
public User GetUser(Guid userId)
    {
        return _applicationDbContext.Users.Find(userId);
    }
```

The User class/model looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InstagramHandle { get; set; }
}
```

The ApplicationDbContext class looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

Find(userId) does not consistently return the corresponding User object. Most of the time, it returns null. Sometimes, seemingly only when I place a breakpoint and debug for several minutes, it returns the right object. When debugging, I can see that the context's Users DbSet looks just right, and the userId looks just right. Both are Guid and the userId in the database/DbSet is definitely correct.

This method, on the other hand, works like a charm:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _applicationDbContext.Users;
    }
```

I have tried Find(), I've tried Where(), I've tried FirstAndDefault() and I've tried Single(). Nothing seems to be working consistently. I am perplexed by this issue, I've never seen anything like it.

I am also having a different problem which may be related, in which I get an "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" error when trying to add an object with a userId foreign key. Just mentioning it in case it helps locate the problem.

**It seems the problem lies with the Guid type. The ID's are stored as VARBINARY(16) in the database, but do not map correctly to C# Guids for some reason. I have no idea how to fix this however.**

Comment: What SQL is being executed when the call fails? Are you sure it's connecting to the correct database? Are you seeing any warnings in the debug output?

Comment: "SELECT `u`.`UserId`, `u`.`EMail`, `u`.`InstagramHandle`, `u`.`Name`
FROM `Users` AS `u`
WHERE `u`.`UserId` = @__get_Item_0
LIMIT 1".

The database is correct, GetUsers() works perfectly.
I don't see any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I'll try to explain what I think I've learned.
There is no issue with LINQ or actually fetching from the database. The problem is that .NET could not convert the Guid properly from MySQL to C#. I fixed it by adding `GuidFormat=LittleEndianBinary16` at the end of my database connection string, which is equivalent to `oldGuids=true`.